# Embeding auto-refreshing element into sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, stocks

Guys, is it possible to add an auto-refreshing element (and by saying element I mean   simple text) from external webpage?
My problem is that i need to embeed an stock price (and only price, without chart) of:
http://finance.google.ca/finance?q=WSE:SNK
into sharepoint 2013 page...
Is there any simple option to make this done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To be more precise, I need this: http://sanokrubber.pl/en/investors#quotations  (but without day choosing button, just the actual data) to embedd into sharepoint 2013 site...

Comment: You did not add any code, so i'll not provide you one either, but some hints. Read about calling external services from sharepoint, ie: https://blog.portiva.nl/2015/01/15/calling-external-rest-service-from-a-sharepoint-hosted-app-using-the-web-proxy/ . Use `setInterval` javascript function to call it continously at specified interval.

Comment: Thanks for reply! But because I'm not even close to understand Java I'm starting quick lessons...